# Cyclotomic units of abelian extension

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $K$ be abelian over $\mathbb Q$, $E_K$ its unit group, $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ be a minimal cyclotomic field containing $K$ and $C$ its cyclotomic units.

By the definition, we know that the group of cyclotomic units of $K$ is defined by 
$C_K:= C\cap E_K$.

I am wondering if there is a definition when $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is not a minimal field containing $K$.

Thanks!!

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this question. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: In my opinion, I think he/she want to ask if we can replace the "minimal" sense of cyclotomic field with a larger cyclotomic field containing K. Maybe, he/she think it holds too.

Comment: @mike - this is my reading too (and Olivier's as well as I see from the edit). Nevertheless a clarification would be welcome; could the submitter please edit the question?